# How to use a new select on the attribute of the first select?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My code is :

```
var serverManager = new ServerManager();
var regex = new Regex("^(http|https)://");
var host = regex.Replace(url, "");
var instance = serverManager.Sites.First(
    site => site.Bindings.First(
        binding => binding.Host == host
    )
);
```

You can see I try to do a second select on the attribute of the first one because `Bindings` is a collection and I need a particular item of this collection. I get this error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding' to 'Bool'.
```

Any idea to resolve that?

Comment: You can edit the title of the question if you have a better idea. :s

Comment: No, you're trying to apply a second *predicate* - you're not performing any "selects".  What are you really trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
var instance = serverManager.Sites.First(
    site => site.Bindings.Any(
        binding => binding.Host == host
    )
);
```

`site.Bindings.First(binding => binding.Host == host)` returns a `Binding`, but it inside of `serverManager.Sites.First(...)`, which in turn expects a predicate (returning a `bool`), not a `Binding`.

The snippet above uses `Any` to get the first site which has a binding with `Host == host`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var instance = serverManager.Sites.SelectMany(b =>b.Bindings).First(
                binding => binding.Host == host);
```

That should fix it.